# ExtJS 6.7.0 - SCSS class not loading

Tags: javascript, extjs, sass, grid, background-color

I'm trying to apply a background-color to a column from a grid in ExtJS here es my code, and I applied sencha app watch so I everything loads, but i keep getting no stiles applied what so ever, what i noticed in th

```
Ext.define('Ris.academic.student.situation.SituationColumn', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.column.Column',
    xtype: 'studentsituationcolumn',

    text: 'Situaciones',
    dataIndex: 'situations',
    renderer(situations) {
        let tags = [];
        (situations || []).forEach(situation => {
            tags.push(
                `<div class="student-situation-tag" style="background-color: ${situation.color}">
                    ${situation.text}
                 </div>`
            );
        });
        return tags.join('');
    }
});
```

and this is the SCSS:

```
.x-grid-cell-inner {
  .student-situation-tag {
    display: flex;
    font-size: smaller;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0 3pt;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-align: center;

    &:not(:first-child) {
      margin-left: 2px;
    }
  }
}

.male-row .x-grid-cell {
  background-color: lightblue; !important;
}

.female-row .x-grid-cell {
  background-color: lightpink; !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You attach style without settings of viewConfig.

I suppose you have something like `getRowClass`:

```
viewConfig: {
        getRowClass: function (record) {
            return record.get('gender') == 'm' ? 'male-row' : 'female-row';
        }
    },
```

in your `grid` configuration.

Look at example on fiddle : https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/35vs

[image]

I don't see any problems there (i used css instead of scss because of fiddle).

Comment: Thank you for your answer!, all tough it shows in the html it doesn't apply the scss for some, before your sugestion it didn't show the class, as you can see in the following image it shos the female-row class followed by two spaces wich means there is something in between that is not applying:
class="female-row  x-grid-row"